# Correct use of tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Here is the example I am working with

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
  & A\arrow[ld,leftrightarrow,"\text{a}"] 
  \arrow[dr,leftrightarrow,"\text{b}"] & \\
  \text{B }
  \arrow[rr,rightarrow,"{c}"] & & d
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

This diagram has the following 3 disadvantages:

1.) a is below the left arrow.

2.) I would like to increase the distance between the top of the triangle A and the bottom of the triangle B and d.

3.) I would like to add some text below the lower arrow. At the moment I only have the letter c appearing on top of the arrow. So how can I add something also below?

Comment: Why the center env? Isn't it centered by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small, row sep=large]
  & A\arrow[ld,leftrightarrow,swap, "\text{a}"]
  \arrow[dr,leftrightarrow,"\text{b}"] & \\
  \text{B }
  \arrow[rr,rightarrow,swap, "{c}"]\arrow[rr, shift left=2.5, phantom,"blah"] & & d
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, almost, I would like to have text both below and above the lower arrow.

Comment: @ArrowMaster1000: I've posted a complement to my code. Please see whether it's fine for you now.

Comment: thank you, it is very nice.

Comment: As an alternative to simplify the syntax you can get both arrow labels labels in the same arrow with `\arrow[rr,rightarrow, "{c}"swap, "d"]` now `swap` only has effect in the label `c` but not in `d`

Answer (score 1):

The label is by default placed to the left of the arrow; left and right are determined as for rivers, looking from the source to the end.

If you want to swap the label position, you just add `'` after the closing double quote, or add the key `swap`.

There can be as many labels as you want, but of course two is the only sensible limit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
  & A\arrow[ld,leftrightarrow,"\mathrm{a}"'] 
  \arrow[dr,leftrightarrow,"\mathrm{b}"] & \\
  B
  \arrow[rr,rightarrow,"\mathrm{c}","\text{text}"'] & & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The same result is obtained with

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
  & A\arrow[ld,leftrightarrow,"\mathrm{a}" swap] 
  \arrow[dr,leftrightarrow,"\mathrm{b}"] & \\
  B
  \arrow[rr,rightarrow,"\mathrm{c}","\text{text}" swap] & & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]